# Create Calculated Column Based on Teams with Four Wins in Final Round Utilizing DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I need a calculated column for champions and runner up. To become a champion, a team must attain 4 wins in a given year in the final round. I just don't know how to translate that for DAX. I want to be able to have a Year Slicer that will show the Champion and Runner Up for a given year in a card.

I have tried a summary table and using TOPN, but since the count of finalists are all one, I am getting no luck. In the picture below, I would like a column delegating if a team is a champion or runner up[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column by clicking in the Modeling tab and selecting 'New Column". Using the code below I created a new column which takes the column which contains the 'Count of Champions' and IF the number is greater than or equal to 4 then "Champion" is placed in the adjacent column, if the number is below 4, then "Runner Up" is placed in the adjacent column.

```
Status = IF(Table1[Count of Champions] >= 4, "Champion", "Runner Up")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please add an explanation to the solution as code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. Thanks! --From Review.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I have a filter on my count of champions for this table that is only counting the "wins". I need to filter the original count of champions by wins only to reflect the graphic above. Then I will be able to replicate your solution. Thanks.

Comment: I used 'code' Total Finalist Wins = CALCULATE(COUNT('Database (2)'[Finalists]), 'Database (2)'[Finalists] = "win") 'code' to get a count of my total wins of 81, instead of filtering like I had in the previous example. When I create a calculated column:Champions = IF([Total Finalist Wins] >= 4, "Champion", "Runner-up"), everything comes back as a Runner Up. I need a way to get the Count by year for the win totals to = 4.